# Am I allowed to divide this equation by the the term $A_1(x){}^2+A_3(x){}^2\propto \sin (\pi x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have this equation
$$ A _1(x)\; \sin \beta+A _2(x)\; \tan \beta + A _3(x)\; \cot \beta+A _4(x)=0,$$
where $A _i(x)$ are functions in terms of $x$, and $x>0$. I want to simplify this equation, and I see that if I divide this equation by $A_1(x)^2+A_3(x)^2$, it will do the job for me, and the result I obtain is correct and coincide with the results of other methods.

My question is that here I see that $A_1(x){}^2+A_3(x){}^2\propto O(x) \sin (\pi  x)$, so, it can be zero for some natural values of $x$. So, then, is this division allowed?

Comment: You can divide by anything which is non-zero. If the solution implies that you divided by a zero valued quantity then that solution is invalidated.

Comment: You could maybe consider first the case when $A_1(x)^2 + A_3(x)^2 \neq 0$, for which you can make the division. Then consider what happens when it is equal to $0$, to make sure that you have not forgotten some solutions.